# Codeigniter Check For Duplicate on Edit Function

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Check For Duplicate on Edit Function

Currently my DB table

```
USERDB
userId userName userPassword userEmail userAddress userPhone
```

What I want

> Allow to check on "userName" duplication" and if "userName" return
>   true , then it allow to edit other textfield.

Problem Met:

> When i did not change anything on my "userName" field , and i edited
>   userEmail, it will always return FALSE due to my "userName" is
>   duplicate with current DB data.

```
$checkvalidation = $this->userdb->UsernameDuplicatechecking($userName);
if($checkvalidation == TRUE){
$this->userdb->updateUser($userName,$userEmail,$userAddress,$userPhone,$id);
}else{
  $this->session->set_flashdata('errormessage', 'Duplicate');
  redirect("User/EditUserAccount/$id");
  }
```

Update Model Code

```
public function updateUser($userName,$userEmail,$userAddress,$userPhone,$id);
{
    $UserArray = array(
                    'userName' => $userName,
                    'userEmail' => $userEmail,
                    'userAddress' => $userAddress,
                    'userPhone' => $userPhone,                  
                  );


    $this->db->set($UserArray);
    $this->db->where('userId',$id);
    $this->db->update('USERDB');        
}
```

Comment: could you show this `updateUser()` codes?

Comment: @HastaDhana added in first post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you please share the code of function UsernameDuplicatechecking($userName) or you can try the below solution and let me know if it helps. Add below function to your userdb model

```
function checkDuplicateUsername($userName)
{
    $this->db->where('userName',$userName);
    $query = $this->db->get('USERDB');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now update your controller function as below:

```
$checkvalidation = $this->userdb->checkDuplicateUsername($userName);
if($checkvalidation == true){
    $this->userdb->updateUser($userName,$userEmail,$userAddress,$userPhone,$id);
}else{
  $this->session->set_flashdata('errormessage', 'Your message here');
  redirect("User/EditUserAccount/$id");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have the username input named `userName`, one solution is you could add a conditional `is_unique` validation, so that if user doesn't change his/her username then don't validate it as unique.
This could be done by pulling user's `userName` from database by id and compare it with the posted `userName` value :

```
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$old_username = $this->db->get_where('USERDB', array('userId' => $id))->row_array();
$original_value = $old_username['userName'];

if($this->input->post('userName') != $original_value) {
    $is_unique =  '|is_unique[USERDB.userName]'
} else {
    $is_unique =  ''
}

$this->form_validation->set_rules('userName', 'User Name', 'required|trim|xss_clean'.$is_unique);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of checking if ($query == true).Check if ($validation == true) and your else condition is wrong as if username is duplicate it will go in the if condition.

Comment: what does it mean ? 
i am confused on this